# Print strings successively

Tags: haskell, io

I have two functions:

```
lowerString :: [Char] -> [Char]
lowerString = filter (/='_')

upperString :: [Char] -> [Char]
upperString [] = []
upperString (x:xs) 
    | x == '_' = x : upperString (tail xs)
    | otherwise = ' ' : upperString(xs)
```

If I apply them on "_A_B_CDEF":

`upperString "_A_B_CDEF"` would return `___` 
`lowerString "_A_B_CDEF"` would return `ABCDEF` 
(without the spaces)

The idea is to have "upperscored" letters (needed for a bigger exercise).

I never worked with Haskell Input/Output (actually this is my 5th day in Haskell). How do I write a function that receive a `[Char]` as input and prints the two strings as output ?

Comment: This sounds like homework - could you comment on that and if it is then fix the tags?  In general you can find this information in tutorials or via hoogle.  Such as [printing](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=String+-%3E+IO+%28%29) or [reading strings](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3a%3a+IO+String).

Comment: Great, then see Kennys answer and use hoogle (it's great).  You'll probably quickly find `getLine` and `putStrLn`.

Comment: Your `upperString` can be written as `map (\x -> if x == '_' then '_' else ' ') "_A_B_CDEF"`.

Comment: @KennyTM You are a little wrong. If i encounter '_' then the result will be '_' and the next character will be skipped. I want to achieve the "upperscore" effect.

Comment: @Andrei: Ah I see. Sorry. In that case `map` cannot be used, but the pattern matching can be done better: `upperString ('_':_:xs) = '_' : upperString xs`, and `upperString (_:xs) = ' ':upperString xs`. Also, you may need to specialize it when the string ends with `'_'`.

Comment: You said something like "wihout the spaces", can you please present the outut as is, not interspersed with sperses, "'s or WTFs?

Comment: @FUZxxl I've edited the question. Now the output doesn't contain any spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would rewrite your functions like this:

```
lowerString :: String -> String
upperString :: String -> String
lowerString = filter (/= '_')
upperString = filter (== '_')
```

Or, if you need the behavior, that each second underscore might be skipped (like: `upperString "_a__bc" == "__"`), something like this:

upperString ('_': _ :xs) = '*' : upperString xs
   upperString ('*': ""   ) = ""
   upperString ( _ : xs   ) = ' ' : upperString xs
   upperString ""           = ""

BTW, now the output of upperString differs from the function definition in your description, as the characters are no longer replaced by spaces, but simply stripped.

For your output problem: You have to do all output in the IO monad. This isn't really difficult, you can use a `do` block to cover this in an imperative look and feel. Any action which may do something to the environment, has the special type IO attached to the output, so you can only run them inside the IO monad itself, or inside a do block:

```
printStrings :: String -> IO () -- () is empty value
printStrings s = do
  putStrLn $ upperString s --This will be executed, like in an imperative language
  putStrLn $ lowerString s
```

Consider reading [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Simple_input_and_output) wikibooks chapter about simple IO.

Answer (score 2):

I/O needs to be done in the IO monad. To read a string, [use the `getLine` action](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v%3AgetLine), and to print it, [use the `putStrLn` action](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v%3aputStrLn), e.g.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  theInput <- getLine
  putStrLn (upperString theInput)
  putStrLn (lowerString theInput)
```

See http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html for how use do basic I/O in Haskell.

Comment: You might not want readLn as that requires your input to be quoted.